# C# Prepared Statements - @ sign (at / strudel sign) queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, prepared-statement, email-validation

I Have a problem with a prepared statement in C#:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = sql.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID FROM userdetails WHERE USER_ID = ?";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@USER_ID", OdbcType.VarChar, 250).Value = email;
```

(of course email contains a valid email address, with @ sign).

This code returns a random error -

> "The connection has been disabled"
>   {"ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][TCP/IP
>   Sockets]ConnectionWrite (send()).
>   ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]General
>   network error. Check your network
>   documentation."}

However if I run my code without a prepared statement, meaning:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID FROM userdetails WHERE USER_ID = '"+email+"'";
```

Everything works perfectly.

Maybe it's related to the fact that I have a @ sign in the parametrized value? I tend to think I'm not the first one trying to create a prepared statement with an email address...

I have no idea what's wrong! Other prepared statements work normally...

Can you please help? :)
Thanks,
Nili

Comment: Hmm. When I do prepared statements, I use named parameters. Something to the extent of `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @id` and then call `.Parameters.Add("@id", email);` -- Try that, see if it works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, ODBC has its share of issues with supporting named parameters.
However, certain usage of named parameters is possible.

For example, in your case the following syntax works:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = sql.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID FROM userdetails WHERE USER_ID = ?";
cmd.Parameters.Add("USER_ID", OdbcType.VarChar, 250).Value = email;
```

More tricky situation is when you don't have a unique match for the parameter like USER_ID = ?; e.g., when you want to use the *IN* operator in the *WHERE* clause.

Then the following syntax would do the job:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = sql.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID FROM userdetails WHERE USER_ID IN (?, ?)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("?ID1", OdbcType.VarChar, 250).Value = email1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?ID2", OdbcType.VarChar, 250).Value = email2;
```

Please note the usage of **?** (question mark) instead of **@** (at sign) within the parameter name. Although note that substitution of parameters' values in this case has nothing to do with their names, but only with their order with the parameters collection.

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: @donstack After executing which line exactly do you get a memory allocation error? What kind of error is it - an exception?

Comment: Thank you. Coming from Java to C# and trying to understand prepared statements was surprisingly hard. This perfectly explains a similar approach to Java, in the bottom example. Phew...

Answer (score 3):

Use '@USER_ID' instead of '?' and all should work:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = sql.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID FROM userdetails WHERE USER_ID = @USER_ID";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@USER_ID", OdbcType.VarChar, 250).Value = email;
```

Comment: The question mark syntax works in all other places. Furthermore, I tried using the syntax you suggested and got a new error - "ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@USER_ID"."

Answer (score 3):

Is there a specific reason you're using `OdbcCommand` rather than using the `SqlClient` provider?

With the `SqlClient` provider, you should be using named parameters as others have suggested.

But [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx):

> The .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB and .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC do not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure. In this case, you must use the question mark (?) placeholder, as in the following example.

So I'm not sure named parameters will work in this case.

Comment: The question mark syntax works in all other places. Furthermore, I tried using the syntax you suggested and got a new error - "ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@USER_ID"."