# How to use string variable in sql statement

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a WPF Application in which I am getting

```
string someone = TextBox.text;
```

I would like to use this in the following query

```
query = " Select * From Table Where Title = someone "
```

How should I go about using the variable someone in the query?

Comment: you shouldnt! Ever hear of SQL Injection or parameterized queries?

Comment: yes, this is very bad practice

Comment: This question is too broad, it amounts to how do i get data from sql server based on user input in a WPF application.  There are entire books just covering that.

Comment: here you can read some SQL Injection examples http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: i feel stupid now :D Ben

Comment: stack overflow will do that to you, with such nice people in the community. the higher the reputation the more carnal the response. love the responses that have no constructive criticism or answers at all; rather, they just tell you you're stupid, what you're doing is wrong, or close your question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can just do this

```
query = "Select * From Table Where Title = " + someone;
```

But that is bad and opens you to SQL Injection

You should just use a parameterized query

Something like this should get you started

```
using (var cn = new SqlClient.SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlClient.SqlCommand())
{
   cn.Open();
   cmd.Connection = cn;
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Table Where Title = @Title";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", someone);
}
```

From Jon Skeet's answer since his was more complete than mine

See the docs for [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for more information.

Basically you shouldn't embed your values within the SQL itself for various reasons:

- It's inelegant to mix code and data
- It opens you up to SQL injection
  attacks unless you're very careful about escaping
- You have to worry about formatting and i18n details for things like numbers, dates and
  times etc
- When the query remains the same with only the values
  changing, the optimizer has less work to do - it can look up the
  previous optimized query directly as it'll be a perfect match in
  terms of the SQL.

Comment: What if I have multiple variable I have to add?

Comment: Use multiple parameters. Would look something like

`cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Table Where Tile = @Title, Thing = @Thing`

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", someone);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Thing, thing);`

Answer (score 14):

You should use a parameterized SQL query:

```
query = "SELECT * From TableName WHERE Title = @Title";

command.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = someone;
```

See the docs for [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for more information.

Basically you shouldn't embed your values within the SQL itself for various reasons:

- It's inelegant to mix code and data
- It opens you up to SQL injection attacks unless you're *very* careful about escaping
- You have to worry about formatting and i18n details for things like numbers, dates and times etc
- When the query remains the same with only the values changing, the optimizer has less work to do - it can look up the previous optimized query directly as it'll be a perfect match in terms of the SQL.

Comment: I pulled in the meat of your answer to mine since mine got accepted so at least someone looking at the accepted answer will see the fullest of information.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to use a C# Prepared sql. [Example on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954877/c-prepared-statements-sign-at-strudel-sign-queries). You don't have to worry about escaping the characters in your sql string or anything

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @SqlQuery varchar(2000), @Fromdate varchar(20), @Todate varchar(20)

set @Fromdate='01 jan 2017'
set @Todate='30 mar 2017'


set @SqlQuery='select * from tblEmployee where tblEmployee.JDate between '''+ @Fromdate + ''' and '''+ @Todate+ ''''

print  @SqlQuery
```