# C# how to get two column values by ID from a datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datatable, datatables

I don't have much knowledge about databases and SQL, so I am trying to get help here, I know this should be basic knowledge though, but as a newbie I am not sure where to start.

I am having a problem figuring out how to get a specific value from datatable, I already have the `ID` in form2 using this code:

```
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserID from Users where UserName='" + textBox1.Text + "' and UserPassword='" + textBox2.Text + "'", cn);
                object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    loginresult = 1;
                    LoginUserID = Convert.ToInt32(result);
                    AdminRights = ???; //how can I get this value from datatable?
                    UserRights = ???; //how can I get this value from datatable?
                    this.Close();
                }
```

Now in form1, I want to get the value of AdminRights or UserRights by ID, I have this code,:

```
        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Button to Form2
        {
            Form2 win_form2 = new Form2();
            win_form2.ShowDialog();
            if (win_form2.loginresult == 1)
            {
                label4.Text = string.Format("User ID: {0}", win_form2.LoginUserID.ToString()); // Gets and places specific user ID
                
                if (win_form2.UserRights = 0 && win_form2.AdminRights = 1) // Check if the ID has AdminRights
                     label5.text = string.Format("Rights: {0}", "Admin") // If true, do the following
                else if (win_form2.UserRights = 1 && win_form2.AdminRights = 0) // Check if the ID has UserRights
                     label5.text = string.Format("Rights: {0}", "User") // If true, do the following
            }
        }
```

My datatable:

- UserID (PK 1,1)
- UserName (string)
- UserPassword (string)
- AdminRights (int) (value could be 0 or 1, and can't be the same value as UserRights)
- UserRights (int) (value could be 0 or 1, and can't be the same value as AdminRights)

So at the end, how can I access to the datatable and get UserRights and AdminRights values in form2?

NOTE: I understand that I have very dangerous code regarding passwords and SQL injection, for now I only want it to work.

Comment: **Warning:** The code in your first code block is wide open to injection attacks! You **need** to *parametrise* your queries. Also the query you have *implies* you are storing plain text passwords; this is also a huge concern. You should be storing password as a hashed and salted value; **never** as plain text.

Comment: I am aware of it, however for now I want it to work, I am still trying to understand SQL overall.

Comment: You need to use either `ExecuteReader` or `Datatable.Load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access columns by name as you can see below, use [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader#getting-schema-information-from-the-datareader) or use i.e. data tables  (but be aware that you should use command parameters and do not put any values in your query directly from user input)

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE UserID = {your_user_id}", connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (_reader.Read())
    {
      // get the results of each column
      var adminRights =  reader["AdminRights "] as string;
      var userRights = reader["AdminRights "] as string;
    }
}

// usage with parameters
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE UserID =@user", sql);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", your_user_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access SQl columns directly using the below example.

Example:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ....", con)) //Your SQL Query here
                {

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (dr != null)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            employee.AdminRights = dr["AdminRights"].ToString(); //This basically reads the SQL column into an "active reader"
                            employee.UserRights = dr["UserRights"].ToString();

                        }
                    }
              
                }

                con.Close();
}
```

Another way is perhaps to use [variables in SQL](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-variables-basics-and-usage/) and add them as parameters in Windows Forms. [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263893/how-to-use-string-variable-in-sql-statement)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AdminUser", empInfo.AdminUser));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserRights", empInfo.UserRights));
```